# isLocked not working in my android app

Tags: java, android

In my app, isLock is not releasing. I tested the app in Samsung mobile, it Works fine but in Moto G lollipop version, isLock is not releasing. I don't know actual reason of the problem. Please Guide me.. whats the problem..

below is my source code

```
       if(brSocket != null){
        brSocket.close();
        brSocket = null;
        wifii = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        if(wifii == null) {

            return;
        }

          if(isLocked == true) {

            lock = wifii.createMulticastLock("m_Lock");
            if (lock != null) {
                Log.v("W","lock is not null");
                if (lock.isHeld()) {
                    Log.v("i","Release the lock");
                    lock.release();
                }
                isLocked = false;
            }else{
                Log.v("i","lock is NULL");
            }
        }
    }
    if(lanSocket != null){
        lanSocket.close();
        lanSocket = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: no errors nor stacktrace?

Comment: Assuming you are using locks because of multithreading, how do you ensure atomicity and visibility of updates to `isLocked`? Is this code wrapped in a synchronized block?

Comment: yes bro..in a synchronized block